# Redeploy azure bot from bot framework composer

Tags: azure, botframework

I've built a bot using the Microsoft bot framework composer, created the resources, and deployed it to Azure. I've now made further improvements to it on my local version and am trying to redeploy it using the same process only, skipping the Create Azure Resource part of it as i want to just deploy it to the resources already created. Is this how Composer is meant to work? I can't see any information on building upon an initial deployment using Composer.

When i try to Deploy to Azure i get the following:

```
C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Composer\My-Bot>pwsh ./Scripts/deploy.ps1 -name OMG-AUS-HELPDESK -environment Production
The MSBuild project 'C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Composer\My-Bot\BotProject.csproj' has already been initialized with a UserSecretsId.
0
Building models for environment [User.Name] targeting [westus] authoring region
Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource.

(A list of optional LUBUILD command line arguments)

lubuild succeeded
Getting Luis accounts...
Return invalid status code while gettings luis accounts: 401, error message: StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  apim-request-id: (Anonymized)
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Date: Mon, 30 Mar 2020 02:16:13 GMT
  Content-Length: 161
  Content-Type: application/json
}
```

I have checked the LUIS authkey and endpoint settings under appsettings.json and they seem correct.

If anyone has any insight i would be forever grateful.

Thanking you in advance,

Comment: Can you link to the instructions you followed to deploy your bot initially and explain how you've modified them to redeploy?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Kyle, appreciate your time.

I was following the instructions in the microsoft documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot.
This worked fine on the first deployment and i was really impressed with how streamlined it was but now i have made improvements to the bot locally and would like to publish the updated bot to azure so i have repeated just the deploy part but it throws this error when i try.

Comment: So you are deploying by running the deploy.ps1 script? I cannot reproduce your issue but I can see the line in the script that seems to be throwing the error. This problem doesn't appear to have anything to do with Composer or redeployment but rather the Azure CLI and the LUIS API. When you do `az account show` do you see that you're logged in with the account you expect? Have you checked to make sure that account has write permissions for the LUIS authoring resource in the Azure portal and the LUIS app in the LUIS portal?

Comment: Hey Kyle,
Thanks for the follow up. I'm retracing my steps by building from the ground up again.
I executed az account show and got back the details I expected. I think I am confused about 1. where to find the right publishing key for LUIS and 2. where to input that key so that it can be used as a parameter.
I'll update once I have finished rebuilding the bot. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Have you finished rebuilding the bot?